# identify change in row observation values

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am interested in identifying individuals that go from a 0 to a .5 or a 1. Here is example data:

```
id     x
1      0 
1      1
1      1 
2      0
2     .5
2     .5
3      0  
3      0
```

I want a new df that indicates whether or not each person moved from a 0 to .5 or 1. Something like this;

```
id    endorsed
1      TRUE
2      TRUE
3      FALSE
```

I tried using ifelse for this, but I just can't get the code right. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `aggregate(x ~ id, df1, function(x) sd(x) != 0)` or even `aggregate(x ~ id, df1, any)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option to do a group by 'id', check for `any` values in 'x' that is a 0 and the next value is either 0.5 or 1 (using `lead`) (Assume that the precision is right)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(endorsed = any(x == 0 & lead(x) %in% c( 0.5, 1)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id endorsed
#* <int> <lgl>   
#1     1 TRUE    
#2     2 TRUE    
#3     3 FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), x = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: do you think it matters if x is numeric or a factor?

Comment: @D.Fowler yes, it may matter becuse if it is a factor, then the `levels` may be different

Answer (score 1):

Since they always start with zero, you can just group and ask whether they ever hit 0.5 or 1:

```
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(endorsed = any(x %in% c(0.5, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  cbind(endorsed = x) ~ id,
  df,
  function(v) head(v, 1) == 0 & tail(cummax(v), 1) %in% c(.5, 1)
)
```

gives

```
  id endorsed
1  1     TRUE
2  2     TRUE
3  3    FALSE
```